# WYSIWYG filter - Anchors get wiped out

Tags: wysiwyg, navigation

I'm trying to allow anchors in my ckeditor but they always get wiped out by the WYSIWYG filter module.

For hyperlinks, my allowed attributes in WYSIWYG filter are "a[!href|target<_blank|title|id|name]". Then in the Rules for Element IDs section, I put "anchor*".

So in my content, when I add an anchor named "anchor1", it adds `<p><a id="anchor1" name="anchor1"></a></p>` to the markup, which get replaced by `<p>&nbsp;</p>` once I save the content.

What am I missing to get this to work ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [WYSIWYG Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter) module page it follows TinyMCE [valid elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements) syntax. From that page:

> ! Makes attributes required. If none of the required attributes are
>   set, the element will be removed. For example, "!href".

It looks like your attribute string uses the exclamation mark to make the 'href' attribute required but the `<a>` tag you're putting in your content does not have that attribute so the element is being removed.